# Data flow errors when importing projection and adding sink in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

- I am implementing cache sink in ADF however, I am having issue when importing the projection and adding the sink, there will be error when adding the sink, but when I delete the sink and import the projection then everything is okay.
- For the input, I use query to load data from Synapse Dedicated Pool.

Importing projection only works when I delete the sink.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario and it's working fine in my environment.

[image]

Also I am able to preview data as well after importing the projection.

Importing errors might occur when we are using manual mapping in the sink mapping. When you are resetting the projection in the source, make sure you check the Auto mapping in the sink mapping.

[image]

If the error still persists, I suggest you debug the dataflow through pipeline. Enable the **Write to activity output** option in sink. This step takes the schema at pipeline debug level and if you are able to see the sink output array in the dataflow output, then publish the dataflow and retry at dataflow debug, it will work.

[image]

If the above steps didn't work, then it's better to raise a [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) on this for deeper investigation.